# static_cast through inheritance chain that includes a template will fail to compile

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In the following example, a upcast with a `static_cast` will fail to compile:

```
class B {
public:
    virtual const void func() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class TB {
public:
    virtual const void func() = 0;
    T var;
};

class D : public TB<double> {
public:
   const void func() {
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
   }
};

int main() {

    D *pd = nullptr;
    B *pbs = static_cast<B*>(pd); // Fails
    B *pbd = dynamic_cast<B*>(pd);

}
```

with the error:

> error: invalid static_cast from type ‘D*’ to type ‘B*’ in B *pbc = static_cast(pd);

[Live example](https://ideone.com/eLsr8Z)

What is the explanation for this error?

Comment: Damn, simple typographic error, thanks @Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because `D` isn't actually derived from `B`, because you forgot to make `TB` derive from `B`.

The dynamic cast, however, still compiles because `dynamic_cast` can do "sideways" casts as well---the cast can actually succeed if the `D` object is a subobject of some derived class that is also derived directly or indirectly from `B`. In your example, however, this is not the case, so the cast will just fail at runtime (by returning a null pointer).

Comment: Wow ... Ok this question is now close worthy.